# Open image view image in fullscreen, and swipe to dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Any suggestions on how I can open a image in fullscreen by tapping on it, and then swipe to hide the image?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

*Add a view programmatically and push it to your stack.

```
//Code to recognize Tap 
let customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero(top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 50) 
// Or desired dimensions
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

*create and add a `SwipeGestureRecognizer`

Url : [developer.apple.com UITapGestureRecognizer Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html)

Url2: [developer.apple.com UISwipeGestureRecognizer Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/)

Comment: Edited to give you an idea of how to create it.